# How to disable automatic registering of com-object in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, comobject, com-object

When I build the solution in the project, VS2010 registers the com-object automatically on the development PC. 
Is there way to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

This setting is found in the Project properties dialog, under Linker->General->Register Output. Set it to **No** to turn off automatic registration on build.

[image]